# In $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, does an orthogonal basis of integer vectors exist such that none of their coordinates is $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

In $\mathbb{R}^{3}$,
does an orthogonal basis
$\{$
$(a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}),$
$(b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{3}),$
$(c_{1}, c_{2}, c_{3})$
$\}$
exist such that
all $a_{i}, b_{i}, c_{i}$
are integers 
$\neq 0$?

Comment: Then the answer is definitely yes, If you have done some drills in Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization you will meet a lot of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1,2,2) and (2,1,-2) and (2,-2,1)